# Java zip files from streams instantly without using byte[]

Tags: java, spring, download, stream, zip

I want to compress multiples files into a zip files, I'm dealing with big files, and  then download them into the client, for the moment I'm using this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/zip")
public ResponseEntity <StreamingResponseBody> getFile() throws Exception {
    File zippedFile = new File("test.zip");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zippedFile);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    InputStream[] streams = getStreamsFromAzure();
    for (InputStream stream: streams) {
        addToZipFile(zos, stream);
    }
    final InputStream fecFile = new FileInputStream(zippedFile);
    Long fileLength = zippedFile.length();
    StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream - >
        readAndWrite(fecFile, outputStream);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + "download.zip")
        .contentLength(fileLength)
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
        .body(stream);
}

private void addToZipFile(ZipOutputStream zos, InputStream fis) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(generateFileName());
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
}
```

This take a lot of time before all files are zipped and then the downloading start, and for large files this kan take a lot of time, this is the line responsible for the delay:

```
while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
    zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
}
```

So is there a way to download files immediately while their being zipped ?

Comment: thank you for the work you did with teamcenter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead. Rather than using the `ZipOutputStream` to wrap a `FileOutputStream`, writing your zip to a file, then copying it to the client output stream, instead just use the `ZipOutputStream` to wrap the client output stream so that when you add zip entries and data it goes directly to the client. If you want to *also* store it to a file on the server then you can make your `ZipOutputStream` write to a split output stream, to write both locations at once.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getFile() throws Exception {

    InputStream[] streamsToZip = getStreamsFromAzure();

    // You could cache already created zip files, maybe something like this:
    //   String[] pathsOfResourcesToZip = getPathsFromAzure();
    //   String zipId = getZipId(pathsOfResourcesToZip);
    //   if(isZipExist(zipId))
    //     // return that zip file
    //   else do the following

    StreamingResponseBody streamResponse = clientOut -> {
        FileOutputStream zipFileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");

        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new SplitOutputStream(clientOut, zipFileOut));
        for (InputStream in : streamsToZip) {
            addToZipFile(zos, in);
        }
    };

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + "download.zip")
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip")).body(streamResponse);
}


private void addToZipFile(ZipOutputStream zos, InputStream fis) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(generateFileName());
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
}
```

---

```
public static class SplitOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private final OutputStream out1;
    private final OutputStream out2;

    public SplitOutputStream(OutputStream out1, OutputStream out2) {
        this.out1 = out1;
        this.out2 = out2;
    }

    @Override public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out1.write(b);
        out2.write(b);
    }

    @Override public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
        out1.write(b);
        out2.write(b);
    }

    @Override public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out1.write(b, off, len);
        out2.write(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override public void flush() throws IOException {
        out1.flush();
        out2.flush();
    }

    /** Closes all the streams. If there was an IOException this throws the first one. */
    @Override public void close() throws IOException {
        IOException ioException = null;
        for (OutputStream o : new OutputStream[] {
                out1,
                out2 }) {
            try {
                o.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (ioException == null) {
                    ioException = e;
                }
            }
        }
        if (ioException != null) {
            throw ioException;
        }
    }
}
```

For the first request for a set of resources to be zipped you wont know the size that the resulting zip file will be so you can't send the length along with the response since you are streaming the file as it is zipped.

But if you expect there to be repeated requests for the same set of resources to be zipped, then you can cache your zip files and simply return them on any subsequent requests; You will also know the length of the cached zip file so you can send that in the response as well.

If you want to do this then you will have to be able to consistently create the same identifier for each combination of the resources to be zipped, so that you can check if those resources were already zipped and return the cached file if they were. You might be able to could sort the ids (maybe full paths) of the resources that will be zipped and concatenate them to create an id for the zip file.

Comment: Thanks this is work I can see the file being downloaded in the network tab of chrome, and appear after the file is completlly downloaded, so I need to show the progress of download in the client so I need to know the file size (length) to set .contentLength(fileLength) so is there a way to get the size of the zip file ?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't know the size of the zip before you stream it since you are zipping it at the same time as you stream it. This is the sacrifice you have to make for this extra efficiency. However, once you have served one request and created the zip file you could use that cached file for any duplicate requests and you will know its size.

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb You could try to base your progress off of how large you *expect* the zip to be and could update your estimate as progress continues. Depending on what compression algorithm you use that could be somewhere in the area of 70% of the original size, but it also really depends on the content you're compressing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @xtratic, this only simplify version.

- Fixed unable to open zip file in windows by auto closing in try-with-resource
- Remove uneccessary "test.zip" file
- Remove class `SplitOutputStream`
- add block finally close on variable `clientOut` (just to make sure, you can remove it though :) )

  ```
  public StreamingResponseBody yourMethod(Some Params...) {

   Map<String, InputStream> inputStreamMap = // map String file name and input stream
   StreamingResponseBody streamResponse = clientOut -> {
       try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(clientOut)) {
           for (Map.Entry<String, InputStream> entry : inputStreamMap.entrySet()) {
               String filename = entry.getKey();
               try (InputStream inputStream = entry.getValue()) {
                   addToZipFile(zos, filename, inputStream);
               }
           }
       } finally {
           clientOut.close();
       }
   };



   return streamResponse;
  }
  ```

below method add filename parameter and remove `fis.close()`

```
private void addToZipFile(ZipOutputStream zos, String filename, InputStream fis) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(filename);
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```